# Pointer being freed

Tags: c++, pointers, mpi, free, delete-operator

I don't understand what can be wrong in the following code. It generate a "pointer being freed was not allocated" error.

```
#include "mpi.h"

using namespace std;

void changeArray(bool* isPrime){  
    delete[] isPrime;
    isPrime = new bool[10];   
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    int size, rank;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

    bool* isPrime = new bool[1000];

    changeArray(isPrime);

    delete[] isPrime;

    MPI_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

But if I put the code of the function directly in the main, it is ok.
If I don't use MPI it is ok too.
What did I do wrong ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the `isPrime` pointer you define outside of the call to `changeArray()` is not changed by `changeArray()`. Its value is copied into the call, where the array is released, but the newly allocated array's pointer is stored only in this temporary variable that gets destroyed upon leaving the function. After the call, the `isPrime` pointer in `main()` still points to the same location it did before the call, and so the `delete[]` in `main()` tries to free memory that has already been freed.

To observe this yourself, print the value of `isPrime` before and after the call to `changeArray()`, and the value of the newly alocated `isPrime` inside `changeArray()`.

The solution is to pass `isPrime` by reference:

```
void changeArray(bool*& isPrime){  
    delete[] isPrime;
    isPrime = new bool[10];   
}
```